# how to get orignal size of images from camera roll in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a list of images collected from Camera roll from device, now I want to view it like photo gallery image view in windows phone.  my images moving  left to right or vise versa to view all images in the list but fix size of all images , I am not able to do get that orignal size of images in camera roll.

Comment: so what size of images are you getting?

Comment: all images are getting list box size ,i.s. photo captured horizontally & vertically are display same size.

Comment: i think your image control is not set to strech = none and it is set to uniform thats why it is coing in same size as it keeps the whole area with keeping aspect ratio intact or it might be fill which will cause image to fill the whole area.

Comment: i also try to set image property ,strech = "none" & not set height,width property but same result ,then i try to remove listbox property height&width  then all images display in top of the emulator same as scale.....

Comment: anybody can help me,i am freasher windows phone developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve these problem using to set BitmapImage property "DecodePixelWidth = 480"  and xaml file Image  property to set width="auto" also I do not set "Stretch" property for image tag.